# Create a new box with addClass in jQuery when message is posted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a simple messenger app and want every post that is made to appear in its own box. Basically the css class '.styling' should be applied to every message that is posted. I tried to use 'messageTosend.addClass('styling')' but that did not work unfortunately. Thanks for reading or even helping me out!

```
$('.post').on('click', () => {
     let completeChat = $('#content').html();
     let messageTosend = $('.sendMessage').val();
   
     /* tried to write messageTosend.addClass('styling') but did not work unfortunately */
   
     let dt = new Date();
   
     $('#content').html('Date/Time: ' + dt.toLocaleTimeString() + completeChat + '<p>' + messageTosend + '</p>')
});

/* every message should be displayed on its own line, and <p> should not be shown, can't make it work unfortunately */
```

```css
.styling {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="content"> </textarea>
<textarea class="sendMessage" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
    
<button type="submit" class="post">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let messageTosend = $('.sendMessage').val();
```

> tried to write messageTosend.addClass('styling') but did not work unfortunately

This doesn't work because messageTosend is not the element itself, but its value.
To add the class to the element, you should do:

```
$('.sendMessage').addClass("styling");
```